# MongoDB document array count field with aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Hello I want to count a document's field,'sendTime' field is in a document array and the condition is

```
$and:[sendTime:{$gte:startTime},sendTime:{$lte:endTime}]
```

my documents look like this

```
{
    _id:ObjectId("5663c7d23d2a580bac21091b"),
    message:[
        {   
            msg:"1",
            sendTime:ISODate("2015-12-08T09:34:53.128Z")
        },
        {
            msg:"2",
            sendTime:ISODate("2015-12-09T09:34:53.128Z")
        }
        ....
    ]   
},
{
    _id:ObjectId("5663c7d23d2a580bac210912"),
    message:[
        {
            msg:"aaa",
            sendTime:ISODate("2015-12-06T09:34:53.128Z")
        },
        {
            msg:"bbb",
            sendTime:ISODate("2015-12-08T09:34:53.128Z")
        }
        ....
    ]   
}
```

I learn a method from other question to count a field.

```
db.chat.find().map(function(room){
    room.message.map(function(msg){
        if(msg.sendTime >= startTime&&msg.sendTime<=endTime)
            queryTotalMsg++;
    });
});
```

I try to use aggregate to do the same thing

```
db.chat.aggregate([
                    $project:{
                        message:"$message.sendTime"                 
                    }
                ]);
```

but I don't know how can I count sendTime with condition

I don't know aggregate can use for this question.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

refer this

Comment: @RahulChanglani yes I try to use $group to do this but I have no idea how to group then I can count with condition

Comment: Use count: { $sum: 1 } in $group and put your $lte/$gte condition on startTime/endTime in $project for sendTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your condition in a $match and depending if you want to count all array documents as a whole, maybe try $unwind, like ..

```
db.chat.aggregate({$unwind: "$message" }, {$match: {condition}}, {$group: {_id: 1, count: { $sum: 1}}});
```

match reference: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/

Comment: Thank you I got the same count with map function!